# Source attachment does not contain the source for the file drivermanager.class

Tags: java, jdbc

I am trying to connect to DB using JDBC 
My code :-

```
    public static Connection getConnection() {

    String dbName = "test";

    String userName = "test";

    String password = "";

    Connection connection = null;

    try {
        Class.forName("com.myqsl.jdbc.Driver");
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/" + dbName, userName, password);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // connection = null;
        System.out.println("error");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return connection;
}
```

And I am getting java.lang.ClassNotFoundException. I tried attaching rt.jar to the class file editor source but now getting **Source attachment does not contain the source for the file drivermanager.class** just don't know how to proceed

*Note:- using eclipse and not on debugging mode.*

Comment: Can you add the exception as well ?

Comment: I guess you miss the mysql-connector in your classpath. https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java

Comment: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.myqsl.jdbc.Driver
 at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
 at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
 at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
 at overview.connectionDB.getConnection(connectionDB.java:18) @soufrk

Comment: it is `mysql`, not `myqsl`... voting to close as typo. BTW: Loading the driver like this is usually not necessary and hasn't been for 10+ years, and if you do it, you only need to do it once (eg in an initializer), not every time you get a connection.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel even after fixing the typo I am getting the same error

Comment: Then you don't have the MySQL Connector/J driver on your class path. Add it. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2839321/connect-java-to-a-mysql-database (especially the second answer)